# Is it possible to remotely "assist" a Mac OS 10.3.9 system from Windows?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, remote-access

I need to assist my computer-challenged aunt with setting up a new printer to her OS 10.3.9 system. In the past, I've used TeamViewer on Windows, which is dead simple easy to use...which is what I need in this case.

I know TeamViewer has an OS X version, but it requires at least 10.4.

Anyone know of a VERY simple to connect remote "assist" solution that works with 10.3.9? VNC doesn't cut it for me, because it requires configuration on her end, which honestly will not be possible.

Comment: SO is for prorgamming questions, not general IT questions.

Comment: Agree with Mark. I've used Fogcreek Copilot (https://www.copilot.com/), but this question is probably best asked in another forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently Vine Server v2.2 works just great with 10.3.9. The [newest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/) (3.0) only works with 10.4 and up.

You can download this older version of [Vine Server (2.2) here](http://mac.majorgeeks.com/download5079.html).

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a Remote Desktop Facility (which may have to be download explicitly), which allows it to work as a VNC server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Fog Creek's Copilot.

https://www.copilot.com/faq/#t1

Comment: That only works on os 10.4 and up

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Apple Remote Desktop. This is going to be the most reliable "officially" supported solution. Remote desktop is pretty good, but it costs money. In the end you are probably better off upgrading to Leopard with iChat screen sharing. Leopard runs decent on even old powerPC systems.

You might also consider Timbuktu

http://www.netopia.com/software/products/tb2/